# Save two model instances in one updateview

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Am trying to update the User model and UserProfile model in one view but it's not working. No error is shown and no changes are made to the objects. What am I not doing right.
Here is my models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """User information not related to authentication"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    # other fields ignored
```

Here is my serializer.py:

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    first_name = CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=20)
    email = EmailField(required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    username = CharField(max_length=32,validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    password = CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)
    confirm_password = CharField(write_only=True)


    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            validated_data['username'],
            email = validated_data['email'],
            first_name = validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name = validated_data['last_name']
            )
        password = validated_data['password']
        confirm_password = validated_data['confirm_password']

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match'})
        else:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'confirm_password')
```

```
class UserProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = CharField(source='user.username')
    first_name = CharField(source='user.first_name')
    last_name = CharField(source='user.last_name')
    email = CharField(source='user.email')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user',)
        # fields = '__all__'
        # depth = 1

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user = instance.user
        instance.user.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.user.username)
        instance.user.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.user.email)
        instance.user.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.user.first_name)
        instance.user.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.user.last_name)
        instance.save()
        user.save()
        return instance
```

Here is view.py:

```
class UserProfileUpdate(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user'
```

Comment: You make changes to instance.user but call instance.save(). You should also call instance.user.save()

Comment: Included that but nothing is happening.

Comment: Though user and instance.user should reference the same object in memory, for consistency, it's better to use just one. So try to update and save either user or instance.user so things don't get mixed up

Comment: My problem is that the saving/updating is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eric
Try changing your update method to this, the actual update data is under `validated_data['user']`

```py
 def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user = instance.user
        instance.user.username = validated_data['user'].get('username', instance.user.username)
        instance.user.email = validated_data['user'].get('email', instance.user.email)
        instance.user.first_name = validated_data['user'].get('first_name', instance.user.first_name)
        instance.user.last_name = validated_data['user'].get('last_name', instance.user.last_name)
        instance.save()
        user.save()
        return instance
```